# Angular's ng-repeat with predefined markup

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

How to import ready html list of objects to angulars store?

For example in Django template I could do something like:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="product">{{ product.title }}</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="product" ng-repead="product in products">{% verbatim %}{{ product.title }}{% endverbatim %}</div>
```

Django's loop used to output products to user and Angular's loop used for creating new products with javascript.

What is correct way to load data to angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just generate a json representation of your data and assign it to a $scope variable in your controller.

Normally, you would fetch data from server using a REST API, through $http or $resource.

But if you want to avoid the extra calls, you can include the data in the first html, inside a `<script>` tag. Output the data in JSON and assign it to a variable. Then use it wherever you need it.

Like this:

```
<html>
<body>

    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>

    <script>
        var data = { ... your data here, generated by Django when serving the HTML ... }

        ... in your controller...
        $scope.items = data;
        ...
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep. But it contained in separate js file. So i could use Ajax to load data, but i want to transmit it over page html. For example i search for variant like this:

    <div class="product" ng-init="products = [{title: 123}, {title: 456}]" ng-repeat="product in products">...</div>

but it does not work.

Comment: Ok. But your variant uses global scope do transfer data and you must avoid variable names collision. Maybe directly access a controller scope from global javascript?

Comment: But, why do not use your variant... static markup is also a global =). Thank you.

Comment: this is a basic recommendation: you can improve it as needed according to your code and file structure... for instance, you can create a global variable called "initial_data" that holds all of your initial data collections